# Make a SQLContainer read-only in Vaadin 7

Tags: sql, containers, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to display data from a database via the [`SQLContainer`](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.html) and a [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html) in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.5.3.

Is there some way to make that SQLContainer be read-only, to prevent it from making any attempts at updating the database?

Comment: Can't you create a readonly connection to the database?

Comment: SQLContainer gets its own database connection from a DataSource.

Comment: The Gris has a readonly option... (Also in most DB you can define readonly users, use this for the grid ro connection)